# How to get a measure of the 'test count' using SonarJS?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarjs

Is there a way to get a measure of the number of tests in SonarQube JavaScript project?

We currently only have coverage metrics, and SonarQube even identifies the test files as 'Unit test', but I can't find a measure for test count anywhere.

In contrast, on my Java project I do have a test count measure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coverage metrics is provided by SonarJS, while test count is not. You need to use [Generic Test Coverage plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Generic+Test+Coverage) (by providing test execution results in xml format) in order to get it.

Comment: it's a native SQ feature now https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Generic+Test+Data